# IDEA update Maven indices can not update

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Error log No available dir found how fix
Change net always
Every time you click, you get an error
Doesn't seem to connect at all

````
java.lang.RuntimeException: No available dir found
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.createNewDir(MavenIndices.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.createNewDataDir(MavenIndex.java:512)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.updateOrRepair(MavenIndex.java:315)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.updateOrRepair(MavenIndices.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.doUpdateIndices(MavenIndicesManager.java:293)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.access$300(MavenIndicesManager.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager$3.run(MavenIndicesManager.java:257)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:932)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$null$3(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)```
````

Comment: Have you tried File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart?

Comment: Are you behind your proxy repository? do you use some local artifactory or nexus? also, I'm not sure I understand `how fix Change net always Every time you click, you get an error Doesn't seem to connect at all`.

Comment: Yes File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: Using proxy has no effect

Comment: See the official JetBrains [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/troubleshooting-common-maven-issues.html#maven_start_problem) to learn how to solve such problems. Especially the part that starts with **"If you have an indexed repository, but still get a Maven repository error, check the following options"**.